# Gradle cannot resolve dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

In my build.gradle file I have a line in dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.seam.validation', name: 'seam-validation-api', version:'3.1.0.Final'
```

When I try to run the project, e.g. 'test' task, I get an error:

```
> Could not resolve org.jboss.seam.validation:seam-validation-api:3.1.0.Final.
Required by:
    com.smspl.mc5:mc5-web-ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    com.smspl.mc5:mc5-web-ui:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT > com.smspl.mc5:mc5-common-rest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not parse POM /Users/amorfis/.m2/repository/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-api/3.1.0.Final/seam-validation-api-3.1.0.Final.pom
  > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar'
> Could not parse POM https://nexus.softwaremill.com/content/groups/smlcommon-repos/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-api/3.1.0.Final/seam-validation-api-3.1.0.Final.pom
  > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar'
```

I'm aware that the problem is that version of 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar' is not specified in the seam-validation-api pom. It is specified in it's parent, and gradle probably has some problems figuring it out. The parent part of seam-validation-api pom looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>seam-validation-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My gut feeling tells me the problem is in  part. I also tried to add this parent dependency explicitely, by adding new line to build.gradle 'dependencies', but without any luck.

Anyone knows solution to this?

UPDATE: In the parent pom:

```
<groupId>org.jboss.seam.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>seam-validation-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>3.1.0.Final</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
            <artifactId>seam-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${seam.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the parent POM? Is the version for `cdi-api` specified under `<dependency-management>` in the parent POM? Was the parent POM ever downloaded?

Comment: Yes, version for validation-api (I think that's what you meant?) is specified under `<depdenency-management>`, and parent pom was downloaded, but I doubt gradle did it. Probably it was maven. (I am trying to move this module from maven to gradle)

Comment: I mean the dependency with group ID `javax.enterprise` and artifact ID `cdi-api`. That's the module whose version Gradle can't resolve (see error message).

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks. I added seam-validation-api pom fragment, where you can see there is no version for cdi-api given. It is also not in parent pom. There is bom specified in seam-validation-parent, but... I didn't find cdi-api version in bom neither. Wonder where maven does take it from?

Comment: And I have 3 versions of cdi-api in my local repository

Comment: Local Maven repository? Gradle doesn't use that, unless you force it to. In any case, it will always maintain its own dependency cache under `~/.gradle`.

Comment: Gradle doesn't support BOMs, and I'm not sure if it supports transitively included BOMs. You may have to specify your direct dependencies explicitly.

Comment: javax.enterprise:cdi-api is in the depdendencies from the beginning. It doesn't work :(

Comment: I also tried to exclude javax.enterprise:cdi-api from seam-validation-api dependency, but without luck so far.

Comment: If you have a corporate repository, you can fix up the POM yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44627/discussion-between-amorfis-and-peter-niederwieser)

Comment: Gosh, any ideas how to fix it not using pom editing?

Comment: Nope. Looks like pom editing is the only option until it is fixed in gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little research of the problem (only research, NOT a solution):

1. [seam-validation-api-3.1.0.Final.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-api/3.1.0.Final/seam-validation-api-3.1.0.Final.pom) has parent [seam-validation-parent-3.1.0.Final.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-parent/3.1.0.Final/seam-validation-parent-3.1.0.Final.pom)
2. seam-validation-parent-3.1.0.Final.pom has parent [seam-parent-19.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/seam-parent/19/seam-parent-19.pom)
3. The file [seam-parent-4.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/seam-parent/4/seam-parent-4.pom) contained version definition for cdi-api, but seam-parent-19.pom does not.
4. The file [seam-validation-parent-3.0.0.Final.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-parent/3.0.0.Final/seam-validation-parent-3.0.0.Final.pom) did contain dependencyManagement for cdi-api, but newer version [seam-validation-parent-3.1.0.Final.pom](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/seam/validation/seam-validation-parent/3.1.0.Final/seam-validation-parent-3.1.0.Final.pom) does not.

I also looked into the code of GradlePomModuleDescriptorBuilder (the class that throws the abovementioned "Could not resolve..." exception). It seems that the class looks for DependencyManagement sections up the parent-pom chain, but it does not respect resolutionStrategy (or any other definitions from gradle script). So currently it is not possible to augment/override dependencyManagement of POM.

My advice: contact the developer(s) of seam framework and ask them to fix the dependencies.